# Websocket and TCP

Tags: tcp, websocket

According to my knowledge, Websocket is a message-based protocol and using TCP as the transport layer. But TCP itself is a stream-based protocol. Can someone explain

1. how websocket message in segmented in TCP?
2. what is framing in Websocket?
3. what's advantage of using message in Websocket? I saw from [here](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-deep-dive-into-websockets-and-http-2-with-sse-how-to-pick-the-right-path-584e6b8e3bf7) asking that **Why are WebSockets frame-based and not stream-based?**

Correct me if I have any misconception.

Comment: I consider the question as too broad. For all the details of the protocol see the standard [RFC 6455](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455). The main advantage to plain TCP: it can be used with JS in the browser and it can tunnel through proxies, firewalls etc the same way as HTTP(S) can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a specific data format like a webSocket frame over TCP, you just have to define the data format so that the reader of the stream knows where the frame starts and ends based on the format.  One typical way is to send a set of data that includes a fixed size (known in advance) header format that includes a length of the total frame and then you send the rest of the frame that is that length.  The reader can then read the initial fixed size data, read the length out of that and then know how much more to read to get the whole frame.

> what is framing in Websocket?

You can read about the whole webSocket frame [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Format) and here's a look at how a webSocket frame is structured.

```
Frame format:  
​​
      0                   1                   2                   3
      0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
     |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
     |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
     |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
     | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
     +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
     |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
     +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
     | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
     +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
     + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
     |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

> what's advantage of using message in Websocket?

It's unclear what you're asking with this.  Reasons for using a webSocket connection include the following:

1. The ability to "push" data from server to the client at any time.
2. Very low overhead way to send data from either client to server or server to client at any time (much lower overhead for repeated packets than an http request).
3. Ability to have a persistent connection over which you can do many things without having to conform everything to the http request/response format.

Comment: Is the frame mentioned above transport in Data Link Layer or Transport layer

Comment: @WorkingSlave - There is some debate about how to classify it.  On the one hand, it's like any other protocol sitting on top of TCP/IP and protocols in TCP/IP are considered in the application layer.  In the browser world where you can't use TCP/IP directly, webSocket feels more like a transport since it and http are the lowest levels you have access to.  It's all really just semantics.  webSocket is built entirely on top of the underlying transport TCP/IP and, in fact, could be built on top of any other reliable transport.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great answer. I have modified my 3rd question with the reference. Do you have a clue on "Why are WebSockets frame-based and not stream-based?"

Comment: @WorkingSlave - That's not how stack overflow works.  You don't ask a question, get a complete answer, then edit your question to add more to your question.  If you have an additional question after this that you really need an answer for, then start a new question.

Comment: Ok Thanks for you answer.