# Websocket frame size specification

Tags: websocket

This is more a question of interest than necessity;

I am writing a small implication of websocket communication for an embedded system, and found the theoretical size limit of a single frame to be specified at 2^64 bytes.

I have decided to only implement support for the shorter specification of 2^16, but I started wondering, why did they decide to make the max frame size so large, when the specification states that you must use a TCP connection, and TCP has a maximum payload size of 65535 bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebSocket protocol allows each message to be fragmented across multiple TCP/IP packets. This allows a 4Gb message to be split into thousands of TCP/IP packets during transmission.

Note that WebSockets implement a **message** based protocol over the TCP/IP **stream**... [WebSockets is **not** a streaming protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961607/websocket-and-tcp).

For this reason, the TCP/IP packet size limit is irrelevant. The only practical limits are the system's limits and security concerns - can the system handle 64 bit message sizes? is it limited to 32 bits? should users be allowed to send huge messages? what limits should a system impose on the incoming messages in order to prevent users from attacking the system? ... etc'.

Comment: I see, so there is actually some something between the application layer and the transport  layer, which divides and combines data larger than 65535 bytes into multiple frames?

Comment: @NicklasNielsen - yes, there is. The WebSocket implementation is a layer between the TCP/IP layer and the application layer. It concats and divides the TCP/IP stream into WebSocket messages, storing incomplete messages in a buffer (when necessary).

Comment: You are talking about the Websocket implimentation for deviding and concatenating the frames, where the finishing frame bit is used?, but then the 64 bit size would still be unneeded, because each websocket frame would still be a maximum of 65535 bytes. There must be something underneath the websocket layer which can devide and concatenate. From my testing, for example when sending a 100Kb from chrome, i will recieve it as two websocket frames, one of ~75Kb and one of ~25Kb, the 75Kb frame must have been devided into two smaller TCP frames at some point automatically.

Comment: @NicklasNielsen - when I wrote "WebSocket implementation", I meant the implementation of the WebSocket library. It reads data from the TCP/IP stream and divides / concats the data into WebSocket frames and message payloads before forwarding the events / messages to the WebSocket application.